# OKTA IDP initiated SSO how to configure redirect URI

Tags: okta

I am trying to integrate OKTA as service provider to provide access to the custom application for external customers.

1. External Users login to enterprise Idp to access the custom application
2. After successful authentication IDP triggers the IDP-Initiated flow and submits the SAML response to OKTA
3. OKTA checks for the external user information in the SAML assertion and sends these details to Custom API application to identify the user
4. If the user is found, the API returns the required information to OKTA
5. OKTA will initiate the PKCE flow to provide access to the custom application

I was success in configuring the OKTA and external customer IDP. But, Can anyone knows how OKTA will call the custom API application to identify the user information? Also, how to configure the redirect URL?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I don't have an answer to your question as we use PingFederate but I was curious as to how you setup Okta (as the SP) to accommodate the IdP-Initiated call, without having to call back into the IdP for authentication? I ask because, as the IdP, we are calling Okta (as the SP) and the SAML response but the vendor is stating they cannot setup Okta without the IdP URL to call back into to have us, the IdP, authenticate the user. Seems your setup works how we believe it should so wanted to get more details about this.

Comment: This might work better as a comment to the question, rather than an answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).